# Computing Pattern Frequency

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, bioinformatics

I'm trying to make a program that searches through text, and pulls out patterns based on the length of the kmer desired. Then, I want it to turn those patterns into a number using an algorithm I learned from my class, and store those values into a dictionary so I can calculate the frequency of each pattern. I know I could just do it with the patterns themselves, but the goal of the assignment is to return a series of numbers (such as: `2 2 2 1 1 3 2`)

So far, I'm able to recursively call the `pat2num` function, but I can't get it to calculate the algorithm, `4 * pat2Num(pattern) + symbol`. And I haven't even tried implementing the dictionary yet.

```
bases = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 2, 'T': 3}


class ComputingFrequencies:
    def __init__(self, text, k, list):
        self.text = text
        self.k = k
        self.list = list  

    def patternGenerator(self):
        return self.freqPat(self.text, self.k)  #begins the class call

    def freqPat(self, text, k):
        for i in range(0, len(text) - k + 1):   #searches length of text corresponding to size of kmer
            pattern = text[i : k + i]           #pulls out kmer
            self.list.append(pattern)           #appends kmer to list
            print self.list
        return self.pat2Nums(list)              #calls pat2Nums

    def pat2Nums(self, list):
        if len(self.list) == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            for pattern in self.list:           #calls pat2Num for each pattern in list
                self.pat2Num(pattern)        

    def pat2Num(self, pattern):
        if len(pattern) == 0:
            self.list = self.list[1:]           
            self.pat2Nums(self.list)
        else:
            symbol = pattern[-1]                #symbol is last char of pattern
            pattern = pattern[0 : -1]           #pattern is (pattern - last char)
            if symbol in bases:
                symbol = bases[symbol]          #symbol becomes number equivalent
                print symbol
                l = 4 * self.pat2Num(pattern) + symbol   #algorithm for turning pattern into number


 c = ComputingFrequencies('AGTAGT', 3, list())
 c.patternGenerator()
```

UPDATE: I was able to finally get something that works, producing the required output. There was a need to initialize all possible outcomes to 0, as well, hence the large output, mostly of 0's (in case you run it). Here's the code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

bases = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 2, 'T': 3}
algNum = list()
freqArray = dict()

class ComputingFrequencies:
    def __init__(self, text, k, list, list2):
        self.text = text
        self.k = k
        self.list = list
        self.list2 = list2  

    def patternGenerator(self):
        return self.freqPat(self.text, self.k)  #begins the class call

    def freqPat(self, text, k):
        for i in range(0, 4**k):
            freqArray[i] = 0
        for i in range(0, len(text) - k + 1):   #searches length of text corresponding to size of kmer
            pattern = text[i : k + i]           #pulls out kmer
            self.list.append(pattern)           #appends kmer to list
            print self.list
        return self.pat2Nums(list)              #calls pat2Nums

    def pat2Nums(self, list):
        if len(self.list) == 0:
            l = str(freqArray.values())
            m = l.replace(",", "")
            print m
            #r = open('file')
            #r.write(m)
        else:
            pattern = self.list[0]
            return self.pat2Num(pattern)        

    def pat2Num(self, pattern):
       symbol = pattern[-1]                #symbol is last char of pattern
       pattern = pattern[0 : -1]           #pattern is (pattern - last char)
       if symbol in bases:
            symbol = bases[symbol]         #symbol becomes number equivalent
            algNum.append(symbol)
       if len(pattern) > 0:
            return self.pat2Num(pattern)
       else:
            self.algNum(algNum, self.k)

    def algNum(self, list, k):
        while len(algNum) > 0:
            if len(algNum) == self.k:
                symbol = algNum[-1]
                prev = symbol
            else:
                symbol = algNum[-1]
                alg = 4 * prev + symbol
                prev = alg
            del algNum[-1]
        freqArray[alg] = freqArray.get(alg, 0) + 1
        self.list = self.list[1:]
        return self.pat2Nums(self.list)

 c = ComputingFrequencies('AGTAGT', 3, list())
 c.patternGenerator()
```

So basically I pulled the algorithm out of where it was before, had the symbol values stored in another list, and then ran that list of numbers through the algorithm once the pattern length got to 0. It's probably not the prettiest/simplest/best, but it worked. Thanks to all for the edits!

Also, note the recursion limit increase. I'm aware this is probably not great. Any suggestions into iterators is welcome (I haven't learned that yet!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your function `pat2Num()` and the line that calculates `l`. It's not quite clear what `l` is suppose to be calculated as.

Reason being that `l` is stuck in an infinite loop until `pattern == None`. Let's walk through it:

- initiate `pat2Num('AGT')`
- `pattern = 'AGT'`
- `symbol = 'T'`
- pattern becomes `'AG'`
- calculate `l`, but in the formula you recall `pat2Num('AG')` with the new pattern.
- this means `l` was never calculated or stored as anything, since previous call to `pat2Num()` never returned anything to store in `l`.
- Once the function is reinitiated, `symbol` now becomes `G`
- `pattern` now becomes `A`
- calculate `l`, but recall `pat2Num('A')`, never storing anything in `l`
- `symbol` now becomes `A`
- `pattern` now becomes `None`
- calculate `l`, but now `pattern` is nothing, so either a None type error or infinite loop

Go back and think about the line `l = 4 * self.pat2Num(pattern) + symbol` and maybe calculate `l` and store somewhere before recalling function. Then sum values is list or something similar.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, ljc! Thanks for the walk-through and the suggestion. I did something similar a few days back and was able to *finally* get a working program. I've updated the initial post with the new, working program. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. please mark the answer as solved (even if you post your edit as the correct answer), so that others can also benefit from this post. Cheers!